# PHP MYSQL while change field name each time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database to store people's quick links. This is a very basic quick link storage method. The database looks like this:

full_name | 1url | 1name | 2url | 2name | 3url |3 name | 4url |4name | 5url | 5name

^This goes on until 10. I know this is a bad way, but this is for an unprofessional website.

I will want to put the result into an ordered list. But I am unsure how to change the number (1url or 2url) each time?

So currently I have it set up like this in PHP

```
$result = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `full_name`='$loggedin')or die (mysql_error());
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     echo '<li><a href="';
     echo $row['1url'];
     echo '"></a></li>';            
   }
```

But I am having no luck with that! I'm very unsure of what I should do. I want it to display another `<li>` with an `<a>` and the link plus name of the link for each row found.

Thanks! Please be specific with me, as this is new ground! :D

EDIT:

I have also run into another problem. I have used code from peoples' answers and most of them work. However, If one of the fields is blank (so a user has only 6 quick links) it still shows an `<li>`. Now I can't see anyway round this issue. :/

SOLUTION:

Here is what works:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {

       if(!trim($row[$i . 'url'])=='') { 
         echo '<li><a href="';
         echo $row[$i . 'url'];
         echo '">';
         echo $row[$i . 'name'];
         echo '</a></li>';
        } //end of didn't trim  

    }//end for for
}//end of while
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: "I know this is a bad way, but this is for an unprofessional website."      Practice makes perfect, buddy.  In my book, there isn't such a thing as an unprofessional site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `full_name`='$loggedin'")or die (mysql_error());
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
     {
         echo '<li><a href="';
         echo $row[$i . 'url'];
         echo '"></a></li>';
     }            
   }
```

Mind you, this is pretty hacky... I would have just implemented it with 3 columns (maybe 4 using an autoincrement to sort) and then select the rows based on the user, emitting each row. That removes the 10 url limit.

**Edit**

For your second question, have a look at the PHP 'empty' function and break/continue the loop if the function returns true.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works well! Please see my edit about a further problem. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, with a little further research, I have managed to find a solution. Thanks for your help! :D

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot cleaner and easier to change your database setup a little bit.  You could have two tables:

**users**

- id: a unique ID for each user, probably an auto increment int of some sort
- full_name: just as you've used it in your table

**quick_links**

- id: quick link id, probably an auto increment int (or you could do a primary index on user_id+order)
- user_id: the user ID to tell us who this quick_link belongs to
- name: the name of the quick link
- url: the url of the quick link
- order: what order to show this link in

Then you can simply do something like

```
$userid_result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT `id` from `users` WHERE `full_name` = $loggedin;"
);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($userid_result);
$userid = $row[0];

$links_result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * from `quick_links` WHERE `user_id` = $userid ORDER BY `order` ASC;"
);

while($quick_link = mysql_fetch_object($links_result))
{
    printf("<li><a href=\"%s\">%s</a></li>", $quick_link->url, $quick_link->$name);
}
```

Of course you'd need some error checking in there, but that gives you an idea.

Comment: You could also use a join to avoid the two separate queries, but this way is visually simple.

Comment: This will also take care of the second problem you had with outputing empty <li></li> pairs when a link column is blank.  This way (as long as you don't allow empty values to be put in the database) there will be exactly as many _valid_ entries as your users have defined.

Answer (score 0):

You SQL query needs to be passed as a string enclosed in "...":

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `full_name`='$loggedin'" )
             or die (mysql_error());

$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

     $attributeURL  = $i . 'url';
     $attributeName = $i++ . 'name';

     echo '<li>'
        . '<a href="' .  $row[ $attributeURL ] . '">' .  $row[ $attributeName ] . </a>'
        . '</li>'
        ;            


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put some double quotes around your select statement:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `full_name`='$loggedin'") or die (mysql_error());
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     echo '<li><a href="';
     echo $row['1url'];
     echo '"></a></li>';            
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $full_name = array_shift($row);
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i)
  {
    echo '<li><a href=' . htmlspecialchars(array_shift($row)) . '>';
    echo array_shift($row);
    echo '</a></li>';
  }
}
```

[`array_shift`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) returns the first element from an array and removes it from the array at the same time. So the code above removes the `full_name` field from the record and then iterates over the rest of the record, removing and printing a URL and its corresponding name on each iteration.

[`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is used to ensure that a valid `a`-tag is created. Depending on where the name of the link comes from, it should also be used on the name of the link.

Comment: This has failed to work, it displays the URL for the 1st <li> then the name for the next. And so on, so on. I am confused now. But thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Then the fields are not returned by the query in the order that you specified. Do not use `*` as the column specification in queries. List the columns you need explicitly.